# Anjular JS ng-change event

Tags: angularjs

Can anybody point out the mistake here. Why it is not working?

http://fiddle.jshell.net/T3m8Z/4/

```
<div ng-app="app">
        <div ng-controller="ctrl">
            <select  ng-change="selectOption();" >
            <option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>
            <option value="1">Read</option>
            <option value="2">Unread</option>
       </select>
        </div>
    </div>
       var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
             $scope.selectOption = function () {
        debugger;
       alert("test");
    };
        });
```

Comment: Using fiddle is okay but please include the code on this site too.

Comment: @triggerNZ seems that OP is absolutely new in this community so for OP i need to mention that go here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes This is my first time here. But I am in real hurry to get this problem resolved. Please help me with it.

Comment: also, one small thing: you can omit the semicolon in the `ng-change` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add a ng-model to the select element.

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/T3m8Z/5/)

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <select  ng-model="selectOpt" ng-change="selectOption();" >
        <option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>
        <option value="1">Read</option>
        <option value="2">Unread</option>
   </select>
    </div>
</div>



   var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
         $scope.selectOption = function () {
    debugger;
   alert("test");
};
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify a model for select:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <select ng-model="action" ng-change="selectOption();" >
            <option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>
            <option value="1">Read</option>
            <option value="2">Unread</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now it works perfectly :)